# Create donut using pie chart with custom labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I am working on financial data, I intend to figure out how to create a nested pie chart on my data. Specifically, I filtered export and import product data and render nested plot for it. I did render pie chart for each, I am not able to get a correct nested pie chart or donut chart for the data. I looked into possible post on `SO` but didn't find any clue how to get my plot.

**my current output**:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df5=df_from_gist_exp.groupby(['cty_ptn'])['qty1'].sum().nlargest(10)
df6=df_from_gist_imp.groupby(['cty_ptn'])['qty1'].sum().nlargest(10)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.pie(df5, labels=df5.index, autopct='%1.0f%%', radius=1)
ax2.pie(df6, labels=df6.index, autopct='%1.0f%%', radius=1)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**current plot**:

I got this plot after running the above solution:

[image]

**desired plot**

actually I want to render this pie chart or donut chart using the same data:

[image: expected pie chart]

How can I get this plot? Any trick to make this happen? Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look into [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html)?

Comment: @SathishSanjeevi yeah that's what I looked for first, but getting nested pie chart is not intuitive to me. Do you have possible idea for that? thanks

Comment: nested pie chart
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/nested_pie.html
looks like what you want

Comment: I can't recreate your variable `df_from_gist` without considerable effort. Could you put this in a google colab or python notebook hosted on github? I am not familiar enough with matplotlib to solve this from memory. Good luck!

Comment: Getting the text in the center is easy. `plt.text(0, 0, '960 K', fontsize=..., ha='center', va='bottom')`. Experiment to find the best position for the `metric tons`. Positioning all the other texts is quite some work if you want a fully automated solution. Otherwise, just search for the best positions.

Comment: @shanecandoit  `df_from_gist = pd.read_csv('filename')`. Probably the default parameters will do.

Comment: @Jerry Please provide shanecandoit all the required information. Read about [creating a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The data from the gist seems to be 1000 lines all from argentina.  df_export and df_import are empty.  Please just do `print(df5.to_dict())` and paste the result into your question. Same for `df6`. Then remove all the other pandas and csv code, as they are not important for the pie diagram. Also add the output of `print(df_export['qty1'].sum())`, same for import.

Comment: You also need to write code to make df5 and df6 having the same list of countries. Something like finding the 5 with most export and the 5 with most import, combine these lists. Then make sure there are max. 7 countries considered. Then calculate "rest of world". The text labeling of the desired plot is made manually with a program such as inkscape. Just save to svg to get an editable drawing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just made a minimal code to achieve what you wanted:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Pie chart, where the slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise:
lbls = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10]

# Intended to serve something like a global variable
class MyClass:
    i = -1

def func(pct, labels, vals):
    MyClass.i +=1
    # Returns absolute value against the default percentage
    # absolute = int(pct/100.*np.sum(vals))
    # Combine labels and values
    return "{:s}\n{:.0f} %".format(labels[MyClass.i], pct)


fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
# Pie wedgeprops with width being the donut thickness
ax1.pie(sizes, wedgeprops=dict(width=0.7), autopct=lambda pct: func(pct, lbls, sizes),
        shadow=True, startangle=90)
sumstr = 'Total = '+str(np.sum(sizes))
# String on the donut center
ax1.text(0., 0., sumstr, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.

plt.show()
```

This produces the following chart:

[image]

Comment: @Jerry Please add the exact way of how you read the gist to the code of the question.

Comment: Put the bit where you assign `df_from_gist` in the answer, maybe. Also taking just the necessary lines from the file and putting them inside a string would go a long way to meeting people half way. I hope this advice helps, I know debugging like this can be frustrating.

Comment: @Jerry : That's a totally different story. Try some tutorials on how to get dataframes done using pandas. There are plenty of them online. Once you have the hook of it, plug the above plot code to your code. It has the sum in the donut hub now.